# Indexing some string on .net

Tags: vb.net, indexing

i have problem with indexing with my code, in loop like this

```
Dim c As String = "My Miraclce is (COM1)"
```

then what i ask is how can i get a "COM1" and certain my c string is looping until 100 so the COM1 will be to COM100, so can anyone help me?

Comment: _"in loop like this"_ What loop? Maybe the question would be clearer if you'd show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem is bordering on incoherent but, if I'm reading it correctly, you want this:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Dim c = String.Format("My Miracle is (COM{0})", i)

    'Use c here.
Next
```

If you're using VB 2015 or later than you can use string interpolation instead of `String.Format`:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Dim c = $"My Miracle is (COM{i})"

    'Use c here.
Next
```